# "Symbol not found" with adding new op

Tags: tensorflow

I created a custom op but cannot import it from python. Error at command line:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: dlopen(src/./ops/build/preprocessing.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZN10tensorflow14AugmentFunctorIN5Eigen9GpuDeviceEEclERKS2_iiiiiiiPKfPfS7_
  Referenced from: src/./ops/build/preprocessing.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in src/./ops/build/preprocessing.so
```

Here is my source:

Makefile

```
TF_INC = `python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.sysconfig.get_include())"`

ifndef CUDA_HOME
    CUDA_HOME := /usr/local/cuda
endif

CC        = gcc -O2 -pthread
CXX       = g++
GPUCC     = nvcc
CFLAGS    = -std=c++11 -I$(TF_INC) -I"$(CUDA_HOME)/include" -DGOOGLE_CUDA=1
GPUCFLAGS = -c
LFLAGS    = -pthread -shared -fPIC
GPULFLAGS = -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC
CGPUFLAGS = -L$(CUDA_HOME)/lib -L$(CUDA_HOME)/lib64 -lcudart -undefined dynamic_lookup

OUT_DIR   = src/ops/build
PREPROCESSING_SRC = "src/ops/preprocessing/preprocessing.cc" "src/ops/preprocessing/kernels/data_augmentation.cc"
GPU_SRC_DATA_AUG    = "src/ops/preprocessing/kernels/data_augmentation.cu.cc"
GPU_PROD_DATA_AUG   = $(OUT_DIR)/data_augmentation.o
PREPROCESSING_PROD  = $(OUT_DIR)/preprocessing.so

preprocessing:
    $(GPUCC) -g $(CFLAGS) $(GPUCFLAGS) $(GPU_SRC_DATA_AUG) $(GPULFLAGS) $(GPUDEF) -o $(GPU_PROD_DATA_AUG)
    $(CXX) -g $(CFLAGS)  $(PREPROCESSING_SRC) $(GPU_PROD_DATA_AUG) $(LFLAGS) $(CGPUFLAGS) -o $(PREPROCESSING_PROD)
```

test.py

```
import tensorflow as tf
_preprocessing_ops = tf.load_op_library(
    tf.resource_loader.get_path_to_datafile("./ops/build/preprocessing.so"))
```

data_augmentation.h

```
#ifndef FLOWNET_DATA_AUGMENTATION_H_
#define FLOWNET_DATA_AUGMENTATION_H_

namespace tensorflow {
template<typename Device>
struct AugmentFunctor {
  void operator()(const Device& d);
};
} // namespace tensorflow
#endif // FLOWNET_DATA_AUGMENTATION_H_
```

data_augmentation.cc

```
#define EIGEN_USE_THREADS

#include "data_augmentation.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"

namespace tensorflow {
typedef Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice CPUDevice;
typedef Eigen::GpuDevice        GPUDevice;

template<>
struct AugmentFunctor<CPUDevice>{
  void operator()(const CPUDevice& d) {
    // CPU implementation here
  }
};

template<typename Device>
class DataAugmentation : public OpKernel {
  public:
    explicit DataAugmentation(OpKernelConstruction *ctx) : OpKernel(ctx) {}

    void Compute(OpKernelContext *ctx) override {
      // Perform augmentation either on CPU or GPU
      AugmentFunctor<Device>()(ctx->eigen_device<Device>());
    }
};

REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("DataAugmentation")
                        .Device(DEVICE_CPU),
                        DataAugmentation<CPUDevice>)

#if GOOGLE_CUDA

REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("DataAugmentation")
                        .Device(DEVICE_GPU),
                        DataAugmentation<GPUDevice>)
#endif // GOOGLE_CUDA
} // namespace tensorflow
```

data_augmentation.cu.cc

```
#if GOOGLE_CUDA

#define EIGEN_USE_GPU

#include "augmentation_base.h"
#include "data_augmentation.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/util/cuda_kernel_helper.h"

namespace tensorflow {
__global__ void SpatialAugmentation() {
   // CUDA kernel code goes here
}

template<>
struct AugmentFunctor<GPUDevice>{
  void operator()(const GPUDevice& d) {
    // GPU implementation goes here
    CudaLaunchConfig config = GetCudaLaunchConfig(10, d);
    SpatialAugmentation<<<config.block_count, config.thread_per_block, 0, d.stream()>>>(config.virtual_thread_count);
  }
};

typedef Eigen::GpuDevice GPUDevice;
template struct AugmentFunctor<GPUDevice>;
} // namespace tensorflow
```

Comment: Did you try following the steps in https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op, particularly under the "Use the op in Python" section?